# payable function fail when adding value to it

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I am trying to build a simple logic for giving tokens in exchange of eth without much of success. The example and error is below. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

notes:

- this contract deployed to the kovan testnet
- when removing the `{ value, from }` config object, it work just fine. (minus the `ethFund.send` which never fire

```
// contract.sol
contract Contract is ERC20 {

    event Gave(address _to, uint256 amount, uint256 ethRate, uint256 amountEth);

    constructor() ERC20("TAHerzelSeventyNine2", "TAHSN2") {
        _mint(msg.sender, toWei(1000000));
        admin = payable(msg.sender);
        ethFund = payable(address(0x...));
    }

    function give(address _to, uint256 _amountOfTokens) payable public {
        uint256 dexBalance = balanceOf(address(this));

        require(msg.sender == admin, "Only Admins allowed to give");
        require(msg.value > 0, "You need to send some ether");
        require(toWei(_amountOfTokens) <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
        transfer(_to, toWei(_amountOfTokens));
        bool sent = ethFund.send(msg.value);
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
        emit Gave(_to, toWei(_amountOfTokens), uint256(getLatestPrice()), uint256(msg.value));
    }

}
```

```
// scripts/index.js
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
// resist sell gospel library gossip claim buddy echo hobby sing exact cabbage
module.exports = async function main (callback) {

    function toWei(amountInEth) {
        return amountInEth * 10**18
    }
    try {
        // Set up a Truffle contract, representing our deployed Box instance
        const _Token = artifacts.require('_Token');
        const token = await _Token.deployed();

        // transfer x tokens to contract
        await token.transfer(token.address, BigInt(toWei(10000)))

        {
            const from = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0]
            const amountInEth = '0.01'
            const value = ethers.utils.parseEther(amountInEth)

            try {                
                const res = await token.give('0x_address', 100, {
                    value: value,
                    from: from,
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log({error})
            }
        }
        callback(0);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        callback(1);
    }
  };
```

```
error:
{
  error: StatusError: Transaction: 0x3327037f1703e0bd3d8ce66f9faa5b4a207a0392a4d71b9d260585fbe0b79fd6 exited with an error (status 0). 
      at main (/Users/example/scripts/index.js:59:41)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    tx: '0x3327037f1703e0bd3d8ce66f9faa5b4a207a0392a4d71b9d260585fbe0b79fd6',
    receipt: {
      blockHash: '0xa265534e55ecaca962185bb590dbe29d2afd542185655155c33f8c1555991223',
      blockNumber: 30415205,
      contractAddress: null,
      cumulativeGasUsed: 21783,
      effectiveGasPrice: '0x9502f908',
      from: '0x80b2468596cdce1fe327ecada1f13f7eacb368f6',
      gasUsed: 21783,
      logs: [],
      logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      status: false,
      to: '0x3e378f102b574483d51c79d3373233a252ddd8a0',
      transactionHash: '0x3327037f1703e0bd3d8ce66f9faa5b4a207a0392a4d71b9d260585fbe0b79fd6',
      transactionIndex: 0,
      type: '0x2',
      rawLogs: []
    },
    reason: undefined,
    hijackedStack: 'StatusError: Transaction: 0x3327037f1703e0bd3d8ce66f9faa5b4a207a0392a4d71b9d260585fbe0b79fd6 exited with an error (status 0). \n' +
      '     Please check that the transaction:\n' +
      '     - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.\n' +
      '     - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.\n' +
      '\n' +
      '    at Object.receipt (/Users/example/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/handlers.js:128:1)\n' +
      '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n' +
      '    at Function.start (/Users/example/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/override.js:49:1)'
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please verify your smart contract? and share it

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa you mean to share the content of my .sol file?

Comment: yes or verify it on kovan